# Is it possible to set session timeout to 1 minute in Asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

For testing purpose I want to set session timeout to 1 minute - is it possible?

I have defined timeout as 1 minute in `web.config`, but it is not working (I heard default timeout is 20 minutes so minimum 20?)

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1"/>
```

Comment: You can also just delete the session cookie, ASPNET_SessionState.  In chrome you can just click & delete, and you can also delete it from javascript.  That will give you a new session, regardless of authentication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can set it to less than 20 minutes. Default 20 doesn't means minimum 20 .

Also, you used `<sessionState>` element of Web.config, so set it as:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1" />
```

Check this forum on asp.net : http://forums.asp.net/t/1725273.aspx/1

Answer (score 2):

A session starts every time a new user hits the website, regardless of whether or not they are anonymous. Authentication has very little to do with Session.

Authentication timeout is the amount of time that the authentication cookie is good for on the user's browser. Once the cookie expires, they must re-authenticate to access protected resources on the site.

So, if Session times out before the Authentication cookie - they are still authenticated, but all their session variables disappear, and may cause errors in your website if you are not disciplined in checking for nulls and other conditions brought about by missing session.

If Authentication times out before the session, then all their session variables will still exist, but they won't be able to access protected resources until they log back in again.

Answer (score 1):

Check this url. It may helpful

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/session-timeout-problem-in-aspnet.html

Answer (score 0):

set `<sessionState mode="StateServer" cookieless="false" timeout="1" />`