# Setting timeout for 1 minute in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, viewstate, one-time-password

I want to set OTP for 1 minute so that it can be expired after 1 minute. I am sending OTP through the email and it is working but the OTP is not getting expired after 1 minute.

below is my code.

This is .cs file

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Configuration;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;
 using System.Web.Security;
 using System.Web.UI;
 using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
 using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
 using System.Xml.Linq;
 using System.Net.Mail;
 using System.Net;

 namespace OTP_Generation
 {
 public partial class OTPThroughEmail : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Sent_OTP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //generate otp
        Random rand = new Random();
        string digits = rand.Next(0, 999999).ToString("D6");

        ViewState["otp"] = digits;

        bool check = sendMail("Your OTP is :" + digits);

        if (check)
        {
            msg.Text = "OTP sent successfully";
        }
        else
        {
            msg.Text = "Error in sending Email";
        }

    }

    public bool sendMail(string msg)
    {
        bool check = false;
        try
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("myid@gmail.com", "myid@gmail.com");
            mail.Subject = "Verify code";
            mail.Body = msg;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587);
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("my@gmail.com", "******");

            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(mail);
            check = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            exception.Text = e.Message;
            check = false;
        }
        return check;

    }

    protected void Verify_OTP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            msg.Text = "Please Enter the OTP";
            return;
        }

        if(textBox.Text.Equals(ViewState["otp"].ToString()))
        {
            msg.Text = "OTP verified";
        }
        else
        {
            msg.Text = "OTP is wrong";
        }


    }
}
}
```

This is .aspx file

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="OTPThroughEmail.aspx.cs" Inherits="OTP_Generation.OTPThroughEmail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
<title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <label id="l" >Enter OTP digit</label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="textBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="Sent_OTP" Text="Sent OTP" runat="server" 
        onclick="Sent_OTP_Click" />
    <asp:Button ID="Verify_OTP" Text="Verify OTP" runat="server" 
        onclick="Verify_OTP_Click" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Label ID="msg" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="exception" runat="server"></asp:Label>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I also set "sessionState" inside "system.web" in Web.config file as

```
<sessionState cookieless="false" timeout="1"></sessionState>
```

When I run above code OTP is verified everytime.
I also tried using Session(replacing ViewState with Session) but it is throwing NullReferenceException in following line:

```
if(textBox.Text.Equals(Session["otp"].ToString()))
```

I searched online but couldn't find the way to set expiration after 1 minute. I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18503784/is-it-possible-to-set-session-timeout-to-1-minute-in-asp-net) but it didn't work.

Please help...
Thanks

Comment: Save current time in `Sent_OTP_Click` handler and retrieve it in `Verify_OTP_Click` using `ViewState` or (better) `Session` (in case the visitor reload the page). `sessionState` has nothing to your problem.

Comment: to be simple, can you just add one more view state, called otp expiryTime, and when you validating your otp, you will check the expiryTime view state first. if it is expiry (check DateTime.Now > expiryTime), if it is expiry, then you simply return error message and clean up the ViewState

Comment: You should store the otp and its expiry in some persistent storage. ViewState and session are not the reliable ways for this kind of feature.

Comment: Thanks @SKLTEZ. It worked.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya How it be done using entity framework for web form application?

Comment: It can be done by creating a table in database to store the Otp information with the userId and expiry time. Create a mapping class and it repository in web application. Store the Otp Data in the database when you create Otp and retrieve Otp data when user enters the Otp and check the expirty time of the Otp with the current DateTime.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bad practice to use Random for generating OTP. Check out TOTP algorithm (RFC 6238), which is designed especially for generating OTPs with limited validity.

Also, take into account, that sending OTP by email is not a real two-factor authentication.

Maybe, for your case OTPs in email and Random as generator will be ok, but in general such practice should be avoided.